# Getting a value from array map and changing value on my chart. JSFiddle included

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle

My [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL998ymf/) with the chart.

How can I specify a specific value in data? For example select the closing value form a certain date.

I'm trying to replace the right red annotation on the chart(127) with a new data value as well as add a string of text after it.

```
data = data.slice(0, 200).map(function(d) {
    return {
        date: parseDate(d.Date),
        open: +d.Open,
        high: +d.High,
        low: +d.Low,
        close: +d.Close,
        volume: +d.Volume
    };
}).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });
```

Also I do not get how both of these annotations have the same .datum value **[data[80]]**, yet have different values on the chart.

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y annotation right")
        .datum([data[80]])
        .call(ohlcRightAnnotation);


svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x annotation top")
        .datum([data[80]])
        .call(timeTopAnnotation);
```

Probably a dumb question but, any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you're looking to do, work with me here.

`data[80]` is plotted on your chart.

It has the following values.

```
date = Fri Feb 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time)
close = 127.08
open  = 127.28
low   = 125.65
high  = 127.28
volume = 54272219
```

To access one of the values, use:

`data[80].close`

try `alert(data[80].close);` as an example.

To change one of the values, use:

`data[80].close = 135.00;`

This code controls which annotations appear, based on the `.call` parameter. So even though it's the same data point, `data[80]`, the call defines which value to be used. For reference, `.attr` defines the placement.

To test, try changing the date of the top annotation like this...

```
data[80].date = new Date();  //change to today's date
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x annotation top")
        .datum([data[80]])
        .call(timeTopAnnotation);
```

Comment: full disclosure: all based on what I found in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. One thing I'm trying to do is change the value of the red annotation to a different value. Right now [data[80]] is deciding the value. I would basically like it to be like this: "(custom number) with Custom text next to it". How could I change [data[80]] to just a variable and then specify whatever # I want with text. But I also want to understand the [data[80]]. What does the 80 mean?

Comment: ok, first, `data` is an array. `80` is the position of the data point we're working with in the array. so if you change `80` to something else like `39`, then the annotation will display the info for data point `39`. (just changed comment, trying to do too many things at once, bare with me)

Comment: Ohh, okay. I knew it was an array but didn't understand how [data[80]] knew from date, close, etc to chose. But since TopAnnotation displays annotation for data[80].date that makes sense. Is there a way I could completely replace "data[80].date" which timeTopAnnotation displays with a new variable?

Comment: that's what I was going to try next but have to run, may be an hour or so, in the mean time, right before the annotation code try: `data[80].date = (your date);`

Comment: Hmm.. I just get "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" .

Comment: sorry I never got back to you last night, look at my edit, did you try it like that?

Comment: It's all good. Yes, I did. Just makes the whole thing disappear.

Comment: ok, at work, they block fiddle here, probably a good thing, i'd be answering questions all day. if no one else chimes in, i'll look again later...